# NSManagedObject convenience init in XCTestCase (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

creating NSManagedObjects like this:

```
let eniyty = MyManagedObject(context: myContext)
```

works well in application, but fails in test with message:
... must have a valid NSEntityDescription.

at other hand this one works well both in application and tests:

```
let eniyty = MyManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: myContext)
```

My entities settings:

[image]

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Show the properties of the Entity (Name, Module, Codegen).

Comment: [![ScreenShot.png](https://postimg.org/image/6kx6u8t4f/)

Comment: Try removing "Current Product Module".

Comment: still doesn't work(( moreover without Current Product Module doesn't work nether in tests nor in app ((

Comment: imho while testing coredata expects to see description of D2RTests.EPair instead of EPair : "An NSManagedObject of class 'D2RTests.EPair' must have a valid NSEntityDescription." -- but i dont see any workaround about it

Comment: Is your manually generated `EPair` `NSManagedObject` subclass contained in the test target?

Comment: sure ) moreover another approach wokks well: let pair = EPair(entity: entityDsc!, insertInto: managedContext)

Comment: Strange. No further idea than, sorry. :-) It works fine in my project, but I let Xcode generate the classes. Good luck.

Comment: @shallowThought thanks again for your help. as i run out of time i gave up and re-created the project. now everything works well.